# Resort array by keys

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my current output for an array:

```
array(7) {
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["opentime"]=>
    float(6)
    ["openspec"]=>
    string(2) "PM"
    ["closetime"]=>
    float(12)
    ["closespec"]=>
    string(2) "AM"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["opentime"]=>
    float(6)
    ["openspec"]=>
    string(2) "PM"
    ["closetime"]=>
    float(12)
    ["closespec"]=>
    string(2) "AM"
  }
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [2]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [3]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [6]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

As you can see the array starts at position 4 and then moves to 5, followed by 0,1,2,3,6.

`I need to preserve the keys but reorganize them so they start at 0 and move towards 6`

Not quite sure how to do this. It seems fairly trivial.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ksort :

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations.

```
ksort($myArray);
var_dump($myArray);
```